# MVC: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am receiving this error from the following code, on the displaynamefor line -

```
@model IEnumerable<AppsByBusiness2.Models.Colleague>
@using Web.Extensions

<h2>Colleagues</h2>

<table class="table">
@{var dummy = Model.FirstOrDefault(); }
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(z => dummy.FirstName)
    </th>
```

I am trying to display the column name for the model in this way because you cannot do it the standard way when a list of models is getting past instead of just a singular one, or at least I could not find a way. This is a solution given on another thread.

Maybe unrelated, but I am also unable to access Colleague at all by doing Model.Colleague but in any online example I've seen you should be able to access the list of models sent to the view in this way.

Comment: could you post your Colleague class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your DisplayNameFor should reference the model, not a variable. Also note that `Model.FirstOrDefault()` could return null so `dummy.FirstName` would throw an exception. So you'll need to decide what to do about exceptions and then amend the following accordingly either by changing FirstOrDefault to First, or using an if statement to only use that code if `Model.Any()`.

```
@model IEnumerable<AppsByBusiness2.Models.Colleague>
@using Web.Extensions

<h2>Colleagues</h2>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(z => z.FirstOrDefault().FirstName)
    </th>
```

Answer (score 6):

If your model is an `IEmumerable<T>` you don't need to create a `dummy` variable since there is an overload of `DisplayNameFor` that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
@model IEnumerable<AppsByBusiness2.Models.Colleague>
@using Web.Extensions

<h2>Colleagues</h2>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName)
    </th>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you have list, you can loop thru all entries in Model

```
@foreach(var dummy in Model){
    <tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(z => dummy.FirstName)
    </th>
    <th>
         ...(other controls)
    </th>
}
```

or even you can set group by....

```
@foreach(var dummy in Model.GroupBy(m => m.FirstName)){
    <tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(z => dummy.FirstOrDefault().FirstName)
    </th>
    <th>
         ...(other controls)
    </th>
}
```

or simply

```
    <tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(z => z.FirstOrDefault().FirstName)
    </th>
    <th>
         ...(other controls)
    </th>
```

or

```
    <tr>
    <th>
         First Name
    </th>
```

:)